# What happens if I call jQuery.post() with an empty url?

Tags: jquery, ajax

If I submit a form with an empty action field, it submits to the current page--is this the case with ajax requests?

Comment: Why don't you try it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's correct, it submits to the current page.

Reference, jQuery documentation:

> **url** (String)
>     Default: The current page
>     A string containing the URL to which the request is sent.

[Source](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: When I tried it, if the url is an empty string (`''`), then the request goes to the current page. This is useful info if your action is dynamically created and can possibly evaluate to an empty string.

Answer (score 9):

I fell over this question when wondering the same about the `$.ajax` method.  It turns out that it works in chrome, but not IE if you have a blank URL.

Comment: This answer helped me fix an IE issue. The solution was to default the url parameter to `window.location.href` if it is not provided.

Answer (score 2):

This parameter is not marked as Optional. Some errors are possible.

http://docs.jquery.com/Post